# C# - Search for Matching FileNames in a Directory using SearchOption

Tags: c#, winforms, search, process

Background: I'm developing a WinForms application using C# with an OpenFileDialog & FileBrowserDialog that will 1) search for a specific string in the filenames of a specified source directory 2) copy files to consolidated directory 3) convert multiple files from excel to csv files, and then 3) convert all the generated csv files into 1 big csv file using a command line executable

Example: MSDN provides a code example that lists all of the directories and files that begin with the letter "c" in "c:\". at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx so I based my code on that...

Problem: The code doesn't copy any files to the consolidated folder so I'm pretty sure the search doesn't work.

What should I change on here? It doesn't work :

```
    string files = "*.xlsx";
    void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, files))
                {
                    // Is this the file we are looking for?
                    // check excel files for corp name in the filename.
                    if (f.Contains(m_sc.get_Corp()))
                    {
                        // check if thread is cancelled
                        if (m_EventStop.WaitOne(0, true))
                        {
                            // clean-up operations may be placed here
                            // ...

                            // inform main thread that this thread stopped
                            m_EventStopped.Set();

                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string path = sDir;
                            string searchPattern = m_sc.get_Corp();

                            // A file has been found in this directory
                            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories(searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                            {

                              try
                              {
                              // Copy each selected xlsx files into the specified TargetFolder 

                              System.IO.File.Copy(FileName, consolidatedFolder + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
                              Log("File" + FileName + " has been copied to " + consolidatedFolder + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName));

                             // Convert each selected XLSX File to CSV Using the command prompt code... 
                              }
                            }
                       }
                  }
```

Comment: @JoshM, I deleted half the other code so the code is easier to analyze. The code doesn't copy any files to the consolidated folder so I'm pretty sure the search doesn't work.

Comment: Have you debugged it? That would be the first step to see if the search is returning anything...

Comment: You have foreach (FileInfo file in files) which implies files is a FileInfo type, yet you have string files = ".xlsx" or is that a typo

Comment: Need more information on this. What error are you getting if getting error at all. What is not work and where in the code? Also, you do not need two loops and recursively calling the DirSearch method. Instead use: string[] filesNames = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, files, SearchOption.AllDirectories);  foreach (string d in filesNames)
                {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've posted does two separate search loops:

first:

```
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, files))
        {
            // Is this the file we are looking for?
            // check excel files for corp name in the filename.
            if (f.Contains(m_sc.get_Corp()))
            {
```

then within that it also does:
                            string path = sDir;
                            string searchPattern = m_sc.get_Corp();

```
                        // A file has been found in this directory
                        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                        DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories(searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                        {
```

In the first one you are looking for files matching `m_sc.get_Corp();`, in the second one you are lookinf for directories...

In fact... your code (pseudo-code?) makes no sense...

Try:

- taking your time
- tidying up the code yourself
- if you rewrite it slowly and break this into smaller chunks, you might spot what you are doing wrong.

Comment: +1 for cleaning up the mess...there is so much crap code on here lately (crap = not very clean and duplicate hunks of code, methods doing 20 things, etc)

Comment: @Stuart, +1 thanks for your response. It's beginning to be a bit too much code to sift through so I've been getting sloppy and making mistakes. Good call. I think i will delete some of the comments on there. How do you recommend I shorted the number of lines of code for the csv conversion and consolidation?

Comment: I'd actually just debug it to look at the problem. if I were debugging this code I'd just put a breakpoint on the first line and then a breakpoint on the first line of each inner loop... you'll soon find out which lines of code are being called and the watch window will tell you what's happening on each line. Once you find a line of code that's not going what you expect, then you can just create a new smaller function to run that little bit of code - either solve the problem with that smaller function yourself - or come back here with a specific question. Hope that helps :) Stuart (a gasbag!)

Comment: @Stuart, the multiselect doesnt work even though I have it set to true. do you know why this might be?

Comment: "the multiselect doesn't work" means nothing to me. Which bit of your code is a multiselect? What does "doesn't work" mean - does it throw an exception? Does it return null? Please give us something to work on!

Comment: ... and I've also no idea what you've set to true either!

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning up a bit, below is some code that will put you on the path, I've excluded the CSV conversion and the merge, hopefully you will get the idea.

```
  private void YourFileRoutine(string sourceDirectoryPath, string consolidatedDirectoryPath)
    {
        var excelFiles = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectoryPath).GetFiles().Where(x => x.Extension == ".xlsx");

        //Copy all Excel Files to consolidated Directory
        foreach (var excelFile in excelFiles)
        {
            FileInfo copiedFile = excelFile.CopyTo(String.Concat(consolidatedDirectoryPath, excelFile.Name)); // Make sure consolidatedDirectoryPath as a "\" maybe use Path.Combine()?

            // ConvertToCSV( Do your CSV conversion here, the Path will be = Path.GetFullPath(copiedFile);
        }

        // Merge CSV's
        var csvFiles = new DirectoryInfo(consolidatedDirectoryPath).GetFiles().Where(x => x.Extension == ".csv");
        // SomeMergeMethod that iterates through this FileInfo collection?

    }
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your response. How do I adapt that to my code though?

Comment: Take it in steps, see if you can get the excel files copied to the new location, once that is done, approach the csv conversion and merge. so just see if you can get the first foreach working and remove the csv portion to first ensure the file copy is working.